# Change numeric column to factor with forcats

Tags: r, forcats

In my continuing quest to make sense of the tidyverse can somebody help me with this?

```
library(tidyverse)
foo <- tibble(x = 1:10, y = rep(1:2,5))
# why does this not work?
foo %>% as_factor(y)
```

I want to change `foo$y` from numeric to a factor. In base R I'd do `foo$y <- as.factor(foo$y)` and be done with it. I would think that `foo %>% as_factor(y)` would be the parsimonious way to do this in tidy-speak but it's not. What is the best way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `pull` the column as a vector and apply

```
library(dplyr)
foo %>%
    pull(y) %>%
    as_factor
```

Or make use of the tidyverse function for transformation

```
foo <- foo %>%
          mutate(y = as_factor(y))
```

Comment: Ok. I see  how that works. I guess I'm surprised that forcats::as_factor doesn't mutate the column. But I see that it never claims that it would. Thanks.

Comment: @user111024 only if you assign to the object i.e. `foo$y <- foo %>%
    pull(y) %>%
    as_factor`

Comment: Got it. The `mutate` isn't needed if you overwrite the column with `foo$y <- ...`

Comment: @user111024 then you are updating the whole object i.e. `foo <- foo %>% mutate(..`